# make first alphabet after space to Upper in text on textBox1_TextChanged event

Tags: c#

I have a query regarding with TextBox.
When I type in the text box the words automatically changes. for example: "my name is kumar" to "My Name Is Kumar" and should be done on textBox1_TextChanged event.

currently i am doing this on Leave event

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + textBox1.Text.Substring(1);
}
```

please help me to accomplished it. lots of thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 7):

Use [TextInfo.ToTitleCase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx)

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 

    TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
    textBox1.Text = myTI.ToTitleCase(textBox1.Text)

}
```

Comment: no no no i dnt want this result after leaving. Instead i want it on text change event. :)

Comment: @user2071493, double click your textbox. then put it down to generated code block.

Comment: i got this when i typed 'my name is kumar' - Ramu Ksa Iema Nym

Comment: @user2071493 are you sure with that? check the `textbox` that you have pass on the method.

Comment: @JW. I get the same behavior too. Interestingly, if you Title Case the string yourself the string is outputted correctly.

Comment: @SandeepKumarThenua Keep in mind that "MY NAME IS KUMAR" is still "MY NAME IS KUMAR" in title case. If the user has their caps lock key on (which I see a lot of people do filling out forms), ToTitleCase() isn't going to change anything. It may be prudent to convert the string to lower case with String.ToLower() first.

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to the previous answer, if you add the following lines to the remainder of the body you'll ensure the correct behavior is maintained:

```
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.TextLength;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
```

So the full solution would be:

```
private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
        //Original from JW's answer
        TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US",false).TextInfo;
        textBox1.Text = myTI.ToTitleCase(textBox1.Text);
        //New lines to ensure the cursor is always at the end of the typed string.
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.TextLength;
        textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextInfo myTI = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
        textBox1.Text = myTI.ToTitleCase(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Regex` here, since it's simpler to implement and I don't think your `TextBox` will hold large strings. Since you want the string to be auto-corrected as you write, you need the `TextChanged` event instead of the `Leave` one:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(" [a-z]");
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(textBox1.Text))
        textBox1.Text = regex.Replace(textBox1.Text, match.Value.ToUpper());
}
```